# popup.html not appearing correctly

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created a page action extension that uses a popup.html file. It used to work perfectly. When I click the icon it displays a small box with only the corner of the popup.html page visible. I set the body and html css height and width but had no luck of making the box bigger. I also moved the css onto another page called popup.css and added  to the popup.html head.

[image: popup.html]

Has anyone run into this issue?
Please help.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup_script.js"></script>
    <link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li id="all">All</li>
        <li id="title">Name</li>
        <li id="artist">Artist</li>
        <li id="album">Album</li>
        <li id="art">Artwork</li>
    </ul>
    <textarea id="info" type="text"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 13pt;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #06477D;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

li {
text-align: center;
padding: 5px 20px;
}

li:hover {
background: #06477D;
color: white;
}

textarea#info {
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: is there something I'm missing?

Comment: try to specify the doctype of your html document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241864/chrome-extension-popup-html-not-display-correctly-anymore)

It's seemed to be a Chrome bug. But it's fixed in Canary-Version. So I think it's just a temporary problem.